# how to create list of ints from a factorial number in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that accepts a natural number n and returns a list of lists arranged in ascending order with integers by the number in the input.
For example: factorial_list (4) → [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
For some reason I'm missing something in the way I wrote the code and would love to get an opinion on how the solution can be completed.

Thank you so much everyone

```
def f_l(n):
    return help([], [], n)

def help(lst, s_l, n):
    if n <= 1:
        s_l.append(n)
        lst.append(s_l)
        return lst
    return lst + help(lst, s_l, n-1)
```

Comment: What's the problem with this?

Comment: its returning a list of [[1], [1], [1], [1]]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `[list(range(1, i+1)) for i in range(1, n+1)]` Need more input cases though.

Comment: yes! thank you but ill be happy to know where am i worng in my recursive way..

Comment: @Aiv Have provided a recursive way here as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59947800/7760998

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial_list(num):
    num_range = [i for i in range(1, num+1)]
    return [num_range[:num] for num in num_range]
```

Above is a simple algorithm for your problem.

```
factorial_list(4)
output: [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach to your problem is

```
lis = []
def fun(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        l = []
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            l.append(j)
        lis.append(l)
    return lis
```

When called as `fun(4)`, it outputs `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

Answer (score 0):

To simplfy the answer of @RonMarcelino, I suggest you this one-line styled solution:

```
def factorial_list(num):
    return [list(range(1, n+1)) for n in range(1, num+1)]

print(factorial_list(4))
# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59947200/how-to-create-list-of-ints-from-a-factorial-number-in-python/#comment106014571_59947200), if you want to do with your recursive way, you need to use

```py
def f_l(n):
    return help([], [], n)

def help(lst, s_l, n):
    if n < 1:
        return [1]
    help(lst, s_l, n-1)
    s_l.append(n)
    lst.append(s_l.copy())
    return lst
```

With `f_l(4)`, you will get `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to return only list of lists arranged in ascending order with integers by the number in the input the following code will help:

```py
def fact(n):
    fact_list = []

    temp = n
    while temp:
        int_list = []
        for i in range(1, temp+1):
            int_list.append(i)
        else:
            int_list.sort()
            fact_list.append(int_list)
            temp -= 1
    else:
        fact_list.sort()

    return fact_list

print fact(4) ## -> python 2.x
print(fact(4)) ## -> python 3.x
```